# Why do i get error in processing pixelation?

Tags: arrays, indexing, processing

I've been trying to copy a p5 script into processing for a school project but I cant completely figure it out. Here you can find the original script : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfLqRuFjK5g

I keep getting this error : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5832960 out of bounds for length 5801040.

Thanks in advance!

```java
PImage img; // creates image variable

int size = 7; // element size

int startx = 0; // starting x coordinate
int starty = 0; // starting y coordinate

void preload() {
}

void setup() {
  size(500, 400); // creates canvas
  
  img = loadImage("Dubbel_augurk-01.jpg"); // preloads Virginia picture
  img.loadPixels(); // loads image
  img.resize(displayWidth, 0); // resizes image to window size
  img.updatePixels(); // updates image

}


void draw() {
  clear();
  background(0);

  int size = floor(map(mouseX, 0, width, 7, 40)); // maps mouseX value to element size

  for (var starty = 0; starty < img.height; starty++) { // creates pixel index
    for (var startx = 0; startx < img.width; startx++) {
      var index = (startx + starty * img.width) * 4;
      var r = img.pixels[index + 0];
      var g = img.pixels[index + 1];
      var b = img.pixels[index + 2];

      //var bright = ((1 * r) + (0.59 * g) + (0.11 * b)); // sets pixel value to adjusted grayscale

      fill(r,g,b); // fills element with adjusted grayscale

      rect(startx, starty, size, size);

      startx = startx + size -1; // set new startx value
    }
    starty = starty + size -1; // set new starty value
  }

}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the programming language you are using and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase Ive been using the processing language. Im finding it hard to understand what the error is and how to tackle it. The error starts at var r=img.pixels[index+0];.  Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, sorry, I haven't seen that [tag:processing] relates to a programming language on its own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between how p5.js (html canvas) stores [`pixels[]`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels) and how Processing's Pimage stores [`pixels[]`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_pixels.html).

While they're both 1D arrays, p5.js `pixels[]` uses 4 values per pixels (e.g. `[r1,g1,b1,a1, r2,g2,b2,a2, ...]`, etc.) and Processing uses 1 value per pixel (e.g. [`pixel1ARGB, pixel2ARGB, etc.`] for `ARGB` image / `[pixel1RGB, pixel2RGB, etc.]` for `RGB` images).

This is why there's a `* 4` on this line in p5.js:

```
var index = (startx + starty * img.width) * 4;
```

Hence the array index out of bounds error: the p5.js `pixels[]` has 4 times more elements than `pixels[]` in Processing.

Remember to also change the data types (you can't use `var` in Processing(java)).

Removing the unused([shadowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) `startx,starty` variables at the top and slightly
renaming them as per Java naming conventions, your snippet would look like this:

```java
PImage img; // creates image variable

int size = 7; // element size

void setup() {
  size(500, 400); // creates canvas
  
  img = loadImage("Dubbel_augurk-01.jpg"); // preloads Virginia picture
  img.loadPixels(); // loads image
  img.resize(displayWidth, 0); // resizes image to window size
  img.updatePixels(); // updates image

}


void draw() {
  clear();
  background(0);

  int size = floor(map(mouseX, 0, width, 7, 40)); // maps mouseX value to element size

  for (int startY = 0; startY < img.height; startY++) { // creates pixel index
    for (int startX = 0; startX < img.width; startX++) {
      int index = (startX + startY * img.width);
      int pixelRGB = img.pixels[index];

      fill(pixelRGB); // fills element with adjusted grayscale

      rect(startX, startY, size, size);

      startX = startX + size -1; // set new startX value
    }
    startY = startY + size -1; // set new startY value
  }

}
```

(Note: this code isn't tested, but hopefully it illustrates the points on pixel indexing)

Bare in mind, the main point of the video tutorial was on accessing/reading individual pixel values and using them in some way (e.g. mapping brightness to shape properties (circle size, line thickness, triangle colour, etc.)).

If you simply want to display a low-res version of the image and don't care about pixel values, it might be simpler to downsample the image (resize smaller), but render at the original size (or larger) with **no aliasing** (to get that crisp pixel art look instead of the blurry aliasing).

Here's a basic example you could run (remember to drag and drop the same "Dubbel_augurk-01.jpg" image on top of this sketchh too):

```java
PImage img; // creates image variable

int downScale = 7; // how many times to scale the image down

void setup() {
  size(500, 400); // creates canvas
  
  // disable aliasing
  noSmooth();
  
  img = loadImage("Dubbel_augurk-01.jpg"); // preloads Virginia picture
  img.resize(img.width / downScale, img.height / downScale); // resizes image  
}


void draw() {
  background(0);

  int size = floor(map(mouseX, 0, width, 7, 40)); // maps mouseX value to element size

  image(img, 0, 0, img.width * size, img.height * size);

}
```

(There are more options out there, but a bit more advanced (for example using [`texture()`](https://processing.org/reference/texture_.html), [`beginShape()`](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html), [`vertex(x, y, u, v)`](https://processing.org/reference/vertex_.html) and aliasing again to scale the texture coordinate or using a fragment shader (via [PShader](https://processing.org/reference/PShader.html)))